# Java 8: modify specific element in the stream by using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to modify a list on int as it follows:

- Every element == 10 needs to be doubled

Here is my attempt:

```js
list.stream()
            .filter(val -> val.getValue() == 10)
            .map(val -> {
                val.doubleValue();
                return val;
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The problem is that I'm filtering the elements, while I would like to keep them all and just modify the ones == 0.

EDIT: the list is composed of elements of `MyType`, defined as it follows:

```js
public class MyType {

    private int val;

    public MyType(int v){
        this.val = v;
    }

    public void doubleVal(){
        val*val;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return val;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Move the condition to the map function, and only increment when it is met? Return unmodified values in all other cases.

Comment: You are squaring val - not doubling it ....

Comment: `val.doubleValue()` doesn't double the value of val, it returns the value of `val` as `double` type (i.e. 10 becomes 10.0).

Comment: Consider `doubleValue` as a function defined by me as `value*value`. If the name is misleading, consider it as `doubleMyVal`.

Comment: @Pavz7 In that case, what's the type of the elements of your List? You said in a comment it was int, but it can't be based on your code.

Comment: @Eran sorry for misleading you. I was trying to keep it simple, then migrate it to the actual type of the list. I updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `filter`. Put all the logic in `map` :

```
list.stream()
    .map(val -> val == 10 ? 2*val : val)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

EDIT : I simplified the code after your clarification that the elements of the list are `Integer`s. Note that the original `List` remains unchanged.

Comment: val is an `int`

Comment: @Pavz7 Then `val.inc()` doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: you are right, there was a typo. I just fixed it. Tried to run your example "fixed" but I'm not getting the values back. I get something like `int@568db2f2`

Comment: I was able to make it work, but it seems that it also modifies the values while I just want to print them. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list is a list of Val, and Val is something like

```
class Val {
  private int v;

  public Val(int v) {
    this.v = v;
  }
  int getValue() {
    return v;
  }

  public void doubleValue() {
    v *= 2;
  }
}
```

then

```
  public static void main(String ... args ) {
        List<Val> ints = Arrays.asList(new Val(1), new Val(5), new Val(10), new Val(2));
        ints.stream().map((v) -> {
            if (v.getValue() == 10) v.doubleValue(); return v;
        }).forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.getValue()));

    }
```

will do the trick.

Comment: ok.. this was based on the question when it had less information ;)

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the condition in map instead of filter.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(10);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(4);

    list.stream().map(val -> {
        if(val < 10){
            return val * val;
        }
        return val;
    }).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This gives out as `10, 25 and 16;`